# Missing Print Objects

Tags: ms-access

I have a report that only shows the table data in the print preview, but none of the static objects (including the borders around text boxes containing table data). There is a subreport on my report which shows the same symptoms. Everything shows correctly in the Report View, but all of the static text, images, labels, borders, etc. do not show up.

I have been using this report for some time now, but recently added another text box to it. This was done after the newest update to MS Access (16.0.11929.20436). However, I added an identical text box to a nearly identical report and do not have the same symptoms on the that report. The only major difference between the two reports is the data that loads in the subreport. The data in the main report is identical.

[Report View][1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj4oz.png

[Print Preview][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rLFF.png

Answer (score 0):

Its likely you have checked the option "print data only" in the print preview options.

Uncheck it and it will show both static and dynamic values.

Comment: I've been working with MS Access for 6 years and I've never noticed that check box before. That was absolutely it and explains the very odd behavior.